# How do I create .npmrc file manually in windows

Tags: windows, npm

I am trying to run npm install and since my connection is behind proxy, I need to set few proxy configurations for npm to read. It seems it has be be placed in .npmrc file.

I don't have this file under C:/users/username/ folder. How do I create this file manually in windows?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 15):

Simply run

```
npm config edit
```

from anywhere in the command prompt or git bash or PowerShell, it will automatically create a global .npmrc file in your C:/users/{userName}/ and launch it using a text editor.

**NOTE:**

```
npm config list
```

**WILL NOT CREATE IT**

Comment: The path ` C:/users/{userName}/`.npmrc` is not a global config but a user level config.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the defaults, run :

```
 npm config ls -l
```

**Global NPM config**

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc
```

**Per-user NPM config**

```
C:\Users\%username%\.npmrc
```

**Built-in NPM config**

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score -1):

Run "npm config edit" it will create new .npmrc file in case the file was not created automatically after node.js installtion